# Punctured Neighborhood Definition

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given the following definition for a punctured neighborhood

"We say that $A$ is a punctured neighborhood of $c$ if there exists d>0 such that $(c-d,c)\cup (c,c+d)$ is a subset of $A$"

However, say if we let
$A = \{c\}\cup (c-d,c)\cup (c,c+d) $
Surely this satisfies the definition because the union is a subset of $A$ (even though it is clearly not a punctured neighborhood of $c$ as it includes $c$)

Could somebody point to the flaw in my reasoning please?

Comment: Yes you are correct, and I can also see why the person who gave you that definition made the mistake they did. Maybe they meant: "We say that $A$ is a punctured neighborhood of $c$ if there exists $d>0$ such that $(c-d,c)\cup(c,c+d)$ is a subset of $A$ and also $c\notin A.$"

Comment: A better definition is to first define a neighborhood of $c$, then define $A$ is a punctured neighborhood of $c$ if $c \notin A$ and $A\cup\{c\}$ is a neighborhood of $c$.